# "where T : X, new()" or "where T : new(), X"?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, generic-programming

What is the difference between the two following generic methods where in first method new() is written first and Book is written last and vice-versa for the last method.

```
public static void Save<T>(T target) where T : new(), Book
{
   ....
}
```

and

```
public static void Save<T>(T target) where T : Book, new()
{
   ....
}
```

where Book is a custom class.

Answer (score 15):

The difference is first one does not compile.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

> `where T : new()`  The type argument must have a public parameterless constructor. **When used together with other constraints, the new() constraint must be specified last.**